# GA analytics reporting API returning 0 for many metrics, but interface shows data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

We query Google Analytics data on behalf of a number of users who oauth on our website. We have a number of cases where we're seeing 0 for all requested metrics for a user, even though the user can see data in the GA UI.

We're using the Python client libraries to retrieve data, using the following code:

```
def traffic_report(profile_id, oauth_cred, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    return _report(profile_id,
               oauth_cred,
               start_date=start_date,
               end_date=end_date,
               metrics=[
                   'ga:users',
                   'ga:sessions',
                   'ga:newUsers',
                   'ga:sessionDuration',
                   'ga:avgSessionDuration',
                   'ga:percentNewSessions',
                   'ga:bounceRate',
                   'ga:pageviews',
                   'ga:pageviewsPerSession',
                   'ga:uniquePageviews',
               ])


def _report(profile_id, oauth_cred, start_date=None, end_date=None, metrics=None, dimensions=None):
    import httplib2
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = oauth_cred.authorize(http)
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    analytics = build(ANALYTICS_API_SERVICE_NAME,
                      ANALYTICS_REPORTING_API_VERSION,
                      http=http,
                      discoveryServiceUrl=ANALYTICS_DISCOVERY_URI)
    metrics_request = [{'expression': metric} for metric in (metrics or [])]
    dimensions_request = [{'name': dimension} for dimension in (dimensions or [])]
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [{
                'viewId': profile_id,
                'dateRanges': [{
                    'startDate': start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                    'endDate': end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                }],
                'metrics': metrics_request,
            }]
        }
    ).execute()
    return response['reports'][0]
```

Anyone know what this might be? I've asked Google but they haven't been much help.

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages from the API? If not, it is possible that your start & end dates are malformed.

Comment: Hi, no error message, the request seems to complete correctly but all metrics are 0

Comment: In that case it seems like you are querying a date range for which no data exists, hence all the 0's. This can happen for a number of reasons: the account wasn't active at that time, GA was incorrectly implemented at the time, etc.

Comment: The user sees data in the interface and has provided screenshots showing data within the range we're querying though.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Are you getting zeroes for all your users, or just some of them?

Comment: Just some, can't really see a pattern either, will add some logging.

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but no this is still an ongoing issue. I tried filing an issue with google, but support is difficult to work with so I gave up and did other stuff.

Comment: I have had the same problem, and what I think is that is related with the GDPR and the time personal information can be retained. If I try to get info (ga:users) by month from more that 5 years ago I have all 0 except the last month that I have the number for today :-(
If I change the start-date to something closer (2017-01-01), everything works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and checked the data retention setting in the property and think the issue might be linked to data retention setting and that the dimension combination happens to be non-standard GA report aggregation.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en

I was missing data for exactly 50 months, turns out user and event data retention setting was set to expire after 50 months.

For dates before 50 months and dimension combination more complicated than what a normal GA report can handle, API request will return 0 for all metrics.